# Get parent props in vue 3 + typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

i have a custom table which looks like the following

```
<template>
  <CustomTable :data="someData">
    <CustomHeaderRow>
      <CustomHeaderColumn>Name</CustomHeaderColumn>
    </CustomHeaderRow>
    <CustomRow v-slot="{ row }">
      <CustomColumn>{{ row.name }}</CustomColumn>
    </CustomRow>
  </CustomTable>
</template>
```

on `CustomRow` i have the following code

```
const instance = getCurrentInstance();
const data = computed(() => instance?.parent!.props.data);
```

the main problem is `CustomRow`'s data is `unknown` type. is there a better way to get parent's data (with correct type) aside from passing it to the child?

Answer (score 1):

> We can solve props drilling with provide and inject. A parent
> component can serve as a dependency provider for all its descendants.
> Any component in the descendant tree, regardless of how deep it is,
> can inject dependencies provided by components up in its parent chain.
> [Prop Drilling](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#prop-drilling)

To provide data to a component's descendants, use the [provide()](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject) function in parent component:

```
<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue'

provide(/* key */ 'message', /* value */ 'hello!')
</script>
```

To inject data provided by an ancestor component, use the [inject()](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#inject) function:

```
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const message = inject('message')
</script>
```

*Update:*
for support typescript, use `InjectionKey`:

> To properly type injected values, Vue provides an InjectionKey
> interface, which is a generic type that extends Symbol. It can be used
> to sync the type of the injected value between the provider and the
> consumer
> [Typing Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-provide-inject)

create a key for:

```
const keyData= Symbol() as InjectionKey<TCustomType>
provide(keyData, customData)
```

and then use this key to access in inject:

```
const customData = inject<TCustomType>(keyData)
```

or

```
const customData = inject(keyData)
```

This way you get full type support in slots and components.

I’ll give you a working example that will help you figure it out if you have any questions. To fully evaluate type support, it is better to open it in VSCODE
[Provide/inject with typescript in action (codesandbox link)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue3-provide-inject-typescript-lpm3jx?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A11%2C17)

Comment: i tried a few minutes ago, but s-slot type is `unknown`

Comment: Added to the answer. I think it will lead you to the right idea.